# iOS: read raw plist

Tags: ios, encoding

I want to read the UserDefaults plist but not as Dictionary or Data. I want it as string like it is when you open it with an editor.

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *homeDir = [documentsPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Documents" withString:@""];
NSString *defaultsPath = [homeDir stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Library/Preferences/%@.plist", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:defaultsPath];
```

Already tried:

```
`NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:defaultsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

which ends up with

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)

Comment: NSData is also one of plist data type, you can't take it for granted that it is utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property list formats can be either binary or text. Binary plists can't be loaded into an `NSString` because strings are for text, not arbitrary binary data. The error you're getting seems to suggest that the file cannot be interpreted as UTF-8, which either means it is encoded using another encoding or is not text at all.

If you are certain that the property list is a text property list, you can use:

```
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:defaultsPath usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
```

This will allow the framework to determine the encoding of the text plist for you. If it isn't a text plist, you can convert it to one using the `plutil` command line utility:

```
plutil -convert xml1 file.plist
```

Or, alternatively you can do this in code by loading the plist using the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nspropertylistserialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-BAJIIGDC) class, obtaining the `NSData` from it that represents the plist as the XML format, and *then* convert that to a string.

An example would be [uncompiled and untested]:

```
// load the file as-is into a data object
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:defaultsPath];

// convert the plist data into actual property list structure
id plistFile = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                          format:NULL
                                                           error:&error];

// get the XML representation of the property list
NSData *asXML = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistFile
                                                           format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];

// convert the NSData object into an NSString object
NSString *asString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asXML encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This should work whether the original plist is in XML or binary format. In this example, I am assuming that the XML representation of the property list is in fact UTF-8 encoded, as this is the most common encoding for XML data.

Comment: @Oskar: Try the above